# Using change of basis to find a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I'm supposed to use a change of basis to express a linear combination of some vectors.

> Consider the invertible $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ below and its inverse $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & -1 & 2\\
> -1 & 2 & -3 \\
> 1 & 1 & 1\\
> \end{bmatrix},\hspace{5mm}A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
> 5 & 3 & -1\\
> -2 & -1 & 1 \\
> -3 & -2 & 1\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
> Suppose that $B=\{\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,\vec{u}_3\}$ and $C=\{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3\}$ are bases for a 3-dimensional vector space $V$, and suppose that $P_{C\leftarrow B}=A$.

> a) Express $2\vec{u}_1+3\vec{u}_2+5\vec{u}_3$ as a linear combination of $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3$.

> b) Express $\vec{v}_1+2\vec{v}_2+3\vec{v}_3$ as a linear combination of $\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,\vec{u}_3$.

My reasoning:

a) Since $P_{C\leftarrow B}=A$, this implies $P_{B\leftarrow C}=A^{-1}$

I assume that since I need to calculate $2\vec{u}_1+3\vec{u}_2+5\vec{u}_3$, I need to write the $u$'s in terms of $v$'s.

I also know that $P_{B\leftarrow C}=A^{-1}$ so this means:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 3 & -1\\
-2 & -1 & 1 \\
-3 & -2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
v_3\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
u_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So this means, I get:

$5v_1+3v_2-v_3=u_1$

$-2v_1-v_2+v_3=u_2$

$-3v_1-2v_2+v_3=u_3$

This implies:

$10v_1+6v_2-2v_3=2u_1$

$-6v_1-3v_2+3v_3=3u_2$

$-15v_1-10v_2+5v_3=5u_3$

So:

$(10v_1+6v_2-2v_3)+(-6v_1-3v_2+3v_3)+(-15v_1-10v_2+5v_3)=-11v_1-7v_2+6v_2$

I assume that I would do the exact same thing for part b), except I'd use $P_{C\leftarrow B}=A$ I think.

Is my thought process correct? It would be great if someone could verify. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to confuse scalars $u_1,u_2,u_3$ with vectors.
Let's keep $u_i$ and $v_i$ denoting vectors and use $x_i$, $y_i$ for coordinates if they occur.

$P_{C\leftarrow B}=A$ means that $A[u_i]_B=[v_i]_B$, that is, since $[u_i]_B=e_i$ the $i$th standard basis vector, the $i$th column of $A$ is $[v_i]_B$, so we have
$$v_1=u_1-u_2+u_3\\
v_2=-u_1+2u_2+u_3\\
v_3=2u_1-3u_2+u_3$$
Can you finish b) from here?

Indeed, for a) you need to do the same with $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Did you mean to write:

$$v_1=u_1-u_2+2u_3\\
v_2=-u_1+2u_2-3u_3\\
v_3=u_1+u_2+u_3$$ instead?

Comment: No, the *column vectors* of $A$ give the other basis vectors.

Comment: Wait doesn't that mean for part a):

$$5v_1+3v_2-v_3=u_1$$

$$-2v_1-v_2+v_3=u_2$$

$$-3v_1-2v_2+v_3=u_3$$

is also wrong and that it should be:

$$5v_1-2v_2-3v_3=u_1$$

$$3v_1-v_2-2v_3=u_2$$

$$-v_1+v_2+v_3=u_3$$

instead?

Comment: Yes, it should be that. Note that in your equation $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ are the coordinate of a single vector in basis $C$ and $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ are the coordinates of the same vector but in basis $B$. Apply it with $v_1=1,v_2=v_3=0$ to obtain the coordinates of the first basis vector of $C$ written in $B$. That's the first column of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry. Am I not simply just doing matrix multiplication in part a)? So would I not just take the dot product between the rows and columns essentially?

Comment: Yes, it's matrix multiplication. Multiplying by the $i$th standard basis vector from the right yields the $i$th column.